# VBA Runtime error While str sql grouping a value

Tags: sql, excel, vba

I am writing below code but showing error can anyone help me

[image]

```
Private Sub cmdShowData_Click()
    'populate Data
    strSQL = "SELECT [OverseasAgent],SUM([Weight]) As [Total] FROM [data$] WHERE  "


    If cmbNetwork.Text <> "" Then
        strSQL = strSQL & " Format([JobDate], 'MMM/YYYY')='" & cmbNetwork.Text & "'"
    End If

    If cmbOrigin.Text <> "" Then
        If cmbNetwork.Text <> "" Then
            strSQL = strSQL & " AND [Branch]='" & cmbOrigin.Text & "'"
        Else
            strSQL = strSQL & " [Branch]='" & cmbOrigin.Text & "'"
        End If
    End If

    If cmbDestination.Text <> "" Then
        If cmbNetwork.Text <> "" Or cmbOrigin.Text <> "" Then
            strSQL = strSQL & " AND [Destn]='" & cmbDestination.Text & "'"
        Else
            strSQL = strSQL & " [Destn]='" & cmbDestination.Text & "'"
        End If
    End If

    If cmdCountry.Text <> "" Then
        If cmbNetwork.Text <> "" Or cmbOrigin.Text <> "" Or cmbDestination.Text <> "" Then
            strSQL = strSQL & " AND [Country]='" & cmdCountry.Text & "'"
        Else
            strSQL = strSQL & " [Country]='" & cmdCountry.Text & "'"
        End If
    End If


    If cmbNetwork.Text <> "" Or cmbOrigin.Text <> "" Or cmbDestination.Text <> "" Or cmdCountry.Text <> "" Then
        'now extract data
        closeRS

        OpenDB

        rs.Open strSQL, cnn, adOpenKeyset, adLockOptimistic
        If rs.RecordCount > 0 Then
            Sheets("View").Visible = True
            Sheets("View").Select
            Range("dataSet").Select
            Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).ClearContents

           'Now putting the data on the sheet
            ActiveCell.CopyFromRecordset rs
        Else
            MsgBox "I was not able to find any matching records.", vbExclamation + vbOKOnly
            Exit Sub
        End If 
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Add a `GROUP BY` clause on `OverseasAgent`.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that `"OverseasAgent"` is in the `SELECT` as the query starts with `"SELECT [OverseasAgent],SUM([Weight]) As [Total] FROM [data$] WHERE"`, but it is not part of the aggregate function `SUM()`.

Try changing the query without the `SUM()` initially to see what yu are getting. Then add it back and add the `Group By OversearsAgent` part. And in general, try running the query hard-coded initially, without all the conditions, coming from a form.

In order to understand exactly what is wrong with the query, write `MsgBox strSQL` before the `rs.Open strSQL` and see how the query looks like. Then examine further.

Comment: With Sum () I am getting no error with selection records, but I need groupby 'OverseasAgent'  and sum(weight). Where I can insert group by in the above query

Comment: @GurusivakumaranKumaran - the keyword in the answer was `MsgBox strSQL` and hardcoding the query. Otherwise it is tough to make it.